# Why doesn't this Javascript code work in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I have code similar to this on the same web page and google chrome loads it just fine. But this particular function only seems to work some browsers. I couldn't find any errors myself. Maybe I could go about writing the statement differently?

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function changeWebsite() {
var currentTime = new Date().getHours();    

 if (7 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 17) {
       document.write(' <img src="http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/images/websitelist_tumblr_VC01.png" width="200" height="45" alt=""> '); 

            document.write(' <a href="http://www.itsnotch.com" <img src="http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/images/websitelist_tumblr_VC02.png" width="200" height="75" border="0" alt="ItsNotch.com"></a> ');

        document.write(' <a href="http://www.notchtheguru.com" <img src="http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/images/NotchTheGuru.comVC.png" width="200" height="119" border="0" alt="Tumblr"></a>');


            document.write('<a href="http://www.bignotch.com" <img src="http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/images/websitelist_tumblr_VC04.png" width="200" height="161" border="0" alt="NotchTheGuru.com"></a>');
      }

       else {
       document.write(' <img src="http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/images/websitelist_tumblr_01.png" width="200" height="45" alt=""> '); 

            document.write(' <a href="http://www.itsnotch.com" <img src="http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/images/websitelist_tumblr_02.png" width="200" height="75" border="0" alt="ItsNotch.com"></a> ');

        document.write(' <a href="http://www.notchtheguru.com" <img src="http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/images/NotchTheGuru.com.png" width="200" height="119" border="0" alt="Tumblr"></a>');


            document.write('<a href="http://www.bignotch.com" <img src="http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/images/websitelist_tumblr_04.png" width="200" height="161" border="0" alt="NotchTheGuru.com"></a>');
      }

      }


changeWebsite();
-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

You're missing the closing bracket on all your anchor tags.

Answer (score 5):

Code works fine, but you didn't close the opening anchor tags.

```
<a href="http://www.notchtheguru.com" <img
```

should be

```
<a href="http://www.notchtheguru.com"> <img
```

Answer (score 1):

The big problem you have with almost all those `document.write()` lines is that they contain broken HTML code.

All of them have the same problem, which is that the `<a>` tag is not closed properly before the `<img>` tag begins -- ie you're missing the `>`.

This kind of syntax error in your HTML is highly likely to produce cross-browser rendering issues.